# How can I edit storyboard elements that go beyond the boundaries of a view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am trying to add an item to my storyboard inside a UIViewController, but there are already a bunch of elements taking up the vertical space inside the interface builder view. Is it possible to directly edit elements of a subview below the boundaries of the UIViewController?

Example: I want to edit the subview highlighted in orange.

[image: Example: I want to edit the subview highlighted in orange.]

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't. You need to edit it while it's in the visible boundaries of the view controller and then update it's constraints once you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the view in IB. On the inspector, change the size to "free form" then increase the vertical height.

Will add more detail once I can get back to my desk and see Xcode in person.